# Minimal length quote for each orator

Tags: oracle

This is my table (`oratorId`, `quote`). one `orator` have 1 or more `quote`(text)

I want choose unique `oratorId` and minimal length `quote` for this `orator`, but this `quote` should be more than 15 characters long.

Comment: What if  orator have 2 quotes, with same length (16 character for example). Then which one quote do you need to choose ?

Comment: any, does not matters whish one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT oratorId, quote from (
    SELECT t.*,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY oratorId ORDER BY len) as rn  FROM (
       SELECT your_table.* , LENGTH(quote) AS len FROM your_table WHERE LENGTH(quote)  > 15
    ) t
) tt
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you, but this also print anoher columns also, how fix?

Comment: Just select columns which you want, I updated query, please try it again